# Extract pdf properties from the pdf URL

Tags: excel, vba, url, pdf, browser

I have a set of 4000 pdf url's which need to extract the document properties such as document created date, document size, number of pages.

**Note:** PDF document should not to be downloaded.

Please give me a suggestion.

Regards,
Aravind

Comment: If you can't use software on the servers these URL's point to, and you don't want to download the PDF files, how do you suggest to know anything about the files? Me thinks you've defined a physical impossibility here...

Comment: If any software is there, suggest that. So i can try it out.

Comment: If it's physically impossible, how can anyone suggest software? Moreover, asking for software recommendations on Stackoverflow is out-of-bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well... i was writing a bit and searching the Internet for a solution to this...

solution without downloading the file not found, and didn't think possible.

but this I made a code that downloads the file , gets its properties , and then deletes it. all completely transparent to the user.

HOW TO USE:
any cell type
=GetPDFData(URL;NumberData)

for ex:
=getPDFData(A2;1)

NumbersData:

1 = Name

2 = DateCreated

3 = DateModificated

4 = PageCount (is "Beta" , sometimes not work lol )

5 = size

6 = kind

And the Code: (paste this in a new module)

```
Public Function GetPDFData(URL As String, TipoDato As Integer) As String

    Dim oFS As Object
    Dim strFilename As String
    CreateFolder
    DownloadFile (URL)
    strFilename = "C:\Temp\pdfTemporal\" & NombreDeArchivo(URL)
    Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Select Case TipoDato
        Case 1
        GetPDFData = NombreDeArchivo(URL)
        Case 2
        GetPDFData = oFS.GetFile(strFilename).DateCreated
        Case 3
        GetPDFData = oFS.GetFile(strFilename).DateLastModified
        Case 4
        GetPDFData = pagecount(strFilename)
        Case 5
        GetPDFData = oFS.GetFile(strFilename).Size / 1024 & "Kb"
        Case 6
        GetPDFData = oFS.GetFile(strFilename).Type
        Case Else
        GetPDFData = "ERROR"
    End Select
    Set oFS = Nothing
    DeleteFolder

End Function

Sub DownloadFile(myURL As String)

    Dim TextUrl As String
    TextUrl = myURL
    Dim WinHttpReq As Object
    Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False
    WinHttpReq.send
    myURL = WinHttpReq.responseBody
    If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
        Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        oStream.Open
        oStream.Type = 1
        oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
        oStream.SaveToFile "c:\Temp\pdfTemporal\" & NombreDeArchivo(TextUrl), 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
        oStream.Close
    End If

End Sub

Sub CreateFolder()
    Dim Path As String, NombreCarpeta As String
    Path = "c:\Temp\"
    NombreCarpeta = "pdfTemporal"
     If Dir(Path, vbDirectory) <> "" Then
       If Dir(Path & NombreCarpeta, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir Path & NombreCarpeta
     End If
End Sub

Sub DeleteFolder()
    On Error Resume Next
     Kill "c:\Temp\pdfTemporal\*.*"
    RmDir "c:\Temp\pdfTemporal\"
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Public Function NombreDeArchivo(URL As String) As String

Dim a As String
Dim esp As String
esp = " "
a = URL
For i = 1 To 500
 esp = esp & " "
Next i
a = Replace(a, "/", esp)
a = Right(a, 500)
a = Trim(a)
NombreDeArchivo = a

End Function

Public Function pagecount(sfilename As String) As String
Dim pages As Long
On Error GoTo a
Dim nFileNum As Integer
Dim s As String
Dim c As Integer
Dim pos, pos1 As Integer
pos = 0
pos1 = 0
c = 0
nFileNum = FreeFile
Open sfilename For Binary Lock Read Write As #nFileNum

  Do Until EOF(nFileNum)
    Input #1, s
    c = c + 1
    If c <= 10 Then
        pos = InStr(s, "/N")
    End If
    pos1 = InStr(s, "/count")
       If pos > 0 Or pos1 > 0 Then
            Close #nFileNum
            s = Trim(Mid(s, pos, 10))
            s = Replace(s, "/N", "")
            s = Replace(s, "/count", "")
            s = Replace(s, " ", "")
            s = Replace(s, "/", "")
            For i = 65 To 125
                    s = Replace(s, Chr(i), "")
            Next
            pages = Val(Trim(s))
            If pages < 0 Then
                pages = 1
            End If
            Close #nFileNum
            pagecount = pages
            Exit Function
        End If
        If c >= 10000 Then
             GoTo a
        End If
  Loop
    Close #nFileNum
    pagecount = pages
    Exit Function
a:
    Close #nFileNum
    pages = 1
    pagecount = pages
    Exit Function
End Function
```

I hope you find it useful, or at least a start

Greetings!

Comment: I forgot to clarify : it is a custom function to excel!!

Comment: Nicolas, Thanks for the work. However, the document created date and modified date gives a wrong data. It shows the actual time. Is there an any solution for that?